# Flutter when button clicked scroll down and open textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have flutter apps. I have a button top of the page and a text field bottom of the page.
I want something that When I clicked the button its scroll down and open the text field. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: post your code, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question: You basically want to focus a textfield when a button is pressed.

```
final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode(); //This is the solution of your problem
final TextField _textField = TextField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'This is your textfield'
  ),
);

final FloatingActionButton _myButton = FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _focusNode.requestFocus(),
        child: Icon(Icons.adjust),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      );
```

Place them in your scaffold and try it:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Change focus example'),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
  children: <Widget> [
    Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*3),
    _textField,
  ]
  )),
  floatingActionButton: _myButton,
);
```